# Weirdest errors with simple C program. Linux Installation corrupted?

Tags: c, linux, ubuntu, putty, ioerror

So this is all of my programcode:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <string.h>

typedef struct {
    unsigned char adr;
    unsigned char type;
} stru;

int main (int argc, char *argv[]){

    while(1){

    stru data;

    data.adr = 5;
    data.type = 4;

    printf("Address: %c, Type: %c \n", data.adr, data.type);

    }

    return 0;   
}
```

I compiled it with "gcc testprog.c -o testprog".

The Output is the following:

```
Address: , Type:
Address: , Type:
Address: , Type:
Address: , Type:
Address: , Type:
Address: , Type:
Address: , Type:
Address: , Type:
Address: , Type:
Address: , Type:
Address: , Type:
^CAddress: , Type:
PuTTYPuTTYPuTTYPuTTYPuTTYPuTTYPuTTYPuTTYPuTTYPuTTYPuTTYPuTTYPuTTYPuTTYPuTTYPuTTYPuTTYPuTTYPuTTYPuTTYPuTTYPuTTYPuTTYPuTTYPuTTYPuTTYPuTTYPuTTYPuTTYPuTTYPuTTYPuTTYPuTTYPuTTYPuTTYPuTTYPuTTYPuTTYPuTTYPuTTYPuTTYPuTTYPuTTYPuTTYPuTTYPuTTYPuTTYPuTTYPuTTYPuTTYPuTTYPuTTYPuTTYPuTTYPuTTYPuTTYPuTTYPuTTYPuTTYPuTTYPuTTYPuTTYPuTTYPuTTYPuTTYPuTTYPuTTYPuTTYPuTTYPuTTYPuTTYPuTTYPuTTYPuTTY^C
```

I'm running Ubuntu 12.04 on a Virtual Box and access it via PuTTY SSH client
I recently installed the 0MQ Library, but I don't think that's causing the error.

If someone has a solution to this, please let me know.
Thank you.

Comment: Please don't typedef the struct.

Comment: @BlankXavier: Please don't recommend ugliness.  :)

Answer (score 4):

I think you want to use `%u` in your format string rather than `%c`.

`%c` interprets the input as an [ASCII character](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII) value, so printing 4 or 5 with `%c` is going to print out something in the control character range. Printing out control characters is probably what's causing all the weird stuff at the bottom of your output.

`%u` expects an unsigned integer as input, and it will convert the integer to a string before printing.

I would recommend that you read a [tutorial](http://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/printf-format-strings.html) or [reference](http://linux.die.net/man/3/printf) on `printf`-style format strings to familiarize yourself with the differences between the many format specifiers.

Comment: Outputting a Ctrl-E (character code 5) is what causes the `PuTTYPuTTYPuTTY` junk.  PuTTY replies to each Ctrl-E with its name (or with whatever other string you configure it to respond with, apparently...but the default is its name).

Answer (score 0):

The infinite loops looks very pointless.

And if you want to treat the `unsigned char` as a small integer, you need to print it with a suitable formatting code, like `%u`.

Comment: of course. the whole program is pretty much pointless. was just too figure out what I did wrong. thanks guys for the help

Answer (score 0):

You are currently printing the values 4 and 5 as characters with the `%c` specifier. Since 4 and 5 are not printable Ascii characters, the terminal doesn't display anything. If you want to see the values '4' and '5' printed, modify your code to `printf("Address: %u, Type: %u \n", data.adr, data.type);` since these are unsigned values.